# realizar esta petición AJAX desde Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs

Soy nuevo en node.js, pero se que puedo realizar peticiones a un API en la mayoria de proyectos utilizo Jquery y AJAX, pero esta vez quiero realizarla por Node.js se puede traducir ese codigo a node.js?

```js
    $.ajax({ 
    url:      'http://www.simiapi.com/ApiSimiweb/response/v21/inmueblesDestacados/total/:cantidad',
 type: 'GET',
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader(
    'Authorization',
    'Basic ' + btoa('Authorization:Token'));
 },
 'dataType': "json",
 success:function(response)
 {
    console.log(response);
 }
    
});
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo ver la documentación de [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) de NodeJS. También tienes la alternativa de usar [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) de NPM. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, ahora se que tengo que utilizar http.request de NodeJS, el problema es que no se como armar la peticion con las mismas caracteristicas de mi peticion Ajax

Answer (score 3):

Para armar la petición usando [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) de [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/es/) debes entender la solicitud AJAX para poder replicarla en Node.

Básicamente realizas una solicitud de tipo `GET`, a una `URL` dada. En dicha solicitud envías una cabecera de autorización personalizada la cual contiene el token. Además esperas que la respuesta del servidor sea de tipo `json`.

Una forma en la que puedes realizar dicha petición usando Node sería la siguiente:

```
const http = require('http'); // <- cargamos el módulo http

const requestedHostname = 'http://www.simiapi.com';
const requestedPort = 80; // <- puerto de escucha del host
const requestedPath = '/ApiSimiweb/response/v21/inmueblesDestacados/total/:cantidad'; // <- :cantidad debe ser sustituido por un valor válido
const headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'Aqui pones tu token', // <- aqui puedes pasar el resultado de tu función que calcula el token
}

const requestOptions = {
  hostname: requestedHostname,
  port: requestedPort,
  path: requestedPath,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers
}

const req = http.request(requestOptions, (response) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`); // <- Vemos el estatus de la respuesta
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`); // <- vemos las cabeceras de la respuesta
  response.setEncoding('utf-8'); // <- es el encoding más usual actualmente
  response.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data); // <- mostramos la data recibida
    let receivedData = JSON.parse(data); // <- esto fallará si la respuesta no es un string JSON válido
  });
});

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(`Error in request: ${error.message}`); // <- mostramos el error si lo hubo
});

req.end(); // <- este comando finaliza la solicitud
```

Espero que esto sea lo que estabas buscando. La verdad no es muy diferente de AJAX. Te recomiendo leer bien la documentación.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar este codigo:

Dependencias:

```
  npm i node-fetch
```

Uso:

```
  //requerimos el modulo
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  
  //Construimos los Header con la autorizacion
  const myHeader = new fetch.Headers({
    'Authorization': token
  });
  //configuracion de la peticion
  const myInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeader,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
  };

  let destination = 'http://www.simiapi.com/ApiSimiweb/response/v21/inmueblesDestacados/total/:cantidad';

  //hacemos la peticion
  const myRequest = new fetch.Request(destination, myInit);

  fetch(myRequest)
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then (data => {
      res.send(data)
  })
```

En el middleware:

```
  let token = req.headers['authorization'];
```

O otro camino con axios:

Dependencias:

```
npm i axios
```

Uso:

```
  //requerimos nuestro modulo
  const axios = require('axios');

  //construimos nuestra peticion
  const myInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Authorization': token },
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
  };

  let destination = 'http://www.simiapi.com/ApiSimiweb/response/v21/inmueblesDestacados/total/:cantidad';

  //obtenemos los resultados
  axios.get(destination, myInit)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data)
      res.send(result.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
```

Comment: En español por favor pues estás en SO en español